# Regular expression library for .Net that supports lazy evaluation

Tags: .net, regex, lazy-evaluation

I'm looking for a regular expression library in .Net that supports lazy evaluation.

Note: I'm specifically looking for lazy evaluation (i.e., the library, instead of immediately returning all matches in a document, only consumes as much of the document as necessary to determine the next match per request), NOT support for lazy quantifiers - though if it also supports lazy quantifiers, I wouldn't object!

Specific details:  I want to be able to run regexes against very large documents with potentially hundreds of thousands of regex matches, and iterate across the results using `IEnumerable<>` semantics, without having to take the up-front cost of finding all matches.

Ideally FOSS in C#, but the only requirement is usability from a .Net 3.5 app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Match class' [`NextMatch` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.nextmatch.aspx) should meet your needs:

> Returns a new Match  with the results
>   for the next match, starting at the
>   position at which the last match ended
>   (at the character after the last
>   matched character).

A quick look at it in Reflector confirms this behavior:

```
public Match NextMatch()
{
    if (this._regex == null)
    {
        return this;
    }
    return this._regex.Run(false, base._length, base._text, this._textbeg,
        this._textend - this._textbeg, this._textpos);
}
```

Check out the linked MSDN reference for an example of its usage. Briefly, the flow would resemble:

```
Match m = rx.Match(input);
while (m.Success) 
{
    // do work
    m = m.NextMatch();
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  All the code samples I've ever seen for the framework classes used Regex.Matches, not not Regex.Match, so I didn't even realize this existed.  I feel dumb, but at least it's an easy solution.  (c:

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the built-in `Regex` class doesn't do this? For example, the [`Match.NextMatch()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.nextmatch.aspx) method would suggest that it's continuing from where it got to...

I *believe* that if you call [`Regex.Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx) it will stop at the first match it comes to, and then continue from there when you call `NextMatch`.